# Django + Psycopg2: InterfaceError: only protocol 3 supported

Tags: django, postgresql

When loading pages in my Django + Postgresql setup I occasionally get this error but not all the time:

## psycopg2 in connect

## InterfaceError: only protocol 3 supported

```
psycopg2/__init__.py ? in connect

        raise TypeError('missing dsn and no parameters')
    else:
        dsn = " ".join(["%s=%s" % (k, _param_escape(str(v)))
            for (k, v) in items])
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
if cursor_factory is not None:
    conn.cursor_factory = cursor_factory
return conn
```

I have absolutely no idea what could be causing this.

My production.py settings file:

```
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': 'mydbname',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
            # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
            'USER': 'myuser',
            'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
            'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
            'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but I've had this come up after shared memory issues on an Ubuntu box.

Comment: This is still an issue. Has anyone found a resolution? I'm using Ubuntu but don't know what to do about a "shared memory issue" :/

Answer (score -1):

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.protocol_version

You didn't provide a version of postgres you are using.
Seems it's older than 7.4.
In that case a solution will be to upgrade version of postgres
 (or install older version of psycopg, but i think it's not good)