# Psycopg2 : raised unexpected: InterfaceError('only protocol 3 supported',)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2, psycopg

I am using Django, PostgreSQL setup using Psycopg2 adapter. After I start my server, after few minutes this error is raised. I checked [Django + Psycopg2: InterfaceError: only protocol 3 supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216465/django-psycopg2-interfaceerror-only-protocol-3-supported) .

It says that the latest version of Psycopg2 needs PostgreSQL with version greater than 7.4. I am using verison 9.3.6 and still this issue arises.

Need solution.

```
[2015-04-04 19:05:19,118: ERROR/MainProcess] Task app.tasks.task1 [44286fc6-fb25-4a17-a385-8d480d3551d6] raised unexpected: InterfaceError('only protocol 3 supported',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/grappr-ant-manager/app/tasks.py", line 74, in task1
    package = Package.objects.filter(package_name =package_name).get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 351, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 122, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 966, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 265, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 700, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 784, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 165, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 138, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 133, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 133, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 130, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
InterfaceError: only protocol 3 supported
```

Comment: If you establish a connection with pyscopg2 directly, do you see the same issues? What's the exact psycopg2 version?

Comment: psycopg version : 2.6

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but I've seen this come up after shared memory issues on an Ubuntu box.