# Only protocol 3 supported

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I try to configure Django with PostgreSQL on Windows 10. When I run server usually I get an error

> only protocol 3 supported

but sometimes the server starts properly.

I installed 32-bit Postgres 9.6 and psycopg2 2.7.1.

In settings.py I have

```
DATABASES = {
 'default': {
  'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
  'NAME': 'postgres',
  'USER': 'django',
  'PASSWORD': 'django',
  'HOST': 'localhost',
  'PORT': '5432',
 }
}
```

Do you know any solutions for the problem?

Comment: Seems to be the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25216465/6464308).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes it seems. But I have younger version of PostgreSQL than 7.4 and it is not working. I have 64-bit Windows and use 32-bit Postgres. Can it have some impact? With 64-bit Postgres nothing worked. With 32 sqlite works but not the Postgres