# Only protocol 3 supported error

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to configure Django with PostgreSQL on Windows Server 2012.

but after a while i get this error 
`only protocol 3 supported`

I'm using Postgres 9.6 and psycopg2 2.7.3 and Django 1.11 and mod_wsgi.

i also tried Postgres 9.5 and psycopg2 2.6 but did not work

In settings.py I have

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
     }
}
```

i read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44881827/only-protocol-3-supported) and also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216465/django-psycopg2-interfaceerror-only-protocol-3-supported) but did not found any solutions.

Do you know any solutions for the problem?

Comment: Are you using the default PostgreSQL configuration? Do you have a firewall of some kind turned on?

Comment: This looks like something is breaking the connection to PostgreSQL. This might be for example your antivirus. Please try to connect to the `localhost:5432` database with command line `psql -h localhost -U postgres postgres` to see if it's really something django or psycopg2 related or not.

Comment: @kichik thank you. it was firewall issue.