# psycopg2.InterfaceError: only protocol 3 supported

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I've created a software that uses PostgreSQL (Version 10.4) as it's DB. I also use Django as an internal API server.
For some reason. in a code block not connected in any way to django (I haven't even ran the `django migrate` because I don't need any DB queries to be made from django) I get this Error:
`psycopg2.InterfaceError: only protocol 3 supported`.

The reason I mention django is that a lot of questions in here about this issue had mention django, so I though it might help. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216465/django-psycopg2-interfaceerror-only-protocol-3-supported) suggests to upgrade Postgres to version > 7.4 and as I wrote above, I have V10.4 and it still happens.

this is the code where it happens:

```
with psycopg2.connect(**self.db) as conn:  # this is where the exception occures
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(query)
        results = cur.fetchall()

        if return_headers:
            colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
            results.insert(0, colnames)

        cur.close()
```

Any idea why would it happen? there are seem to be a lot of questions about this issue on the web with no concrete answer.

Comment: What version of `psycopg2`? Where did you get the Postgres code from?

Answer (score 0):

In your self.db are you providing the correct port? it defaults to 5432 if not provided.
try connecting in this way
`conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres password=secret port=yourport host=yourhost")`